# React fetch data HoC that depends on router params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a HoC that fetches data and either returns a loading screen or the underlying component with the data injected.

Now the problem is that the data being fetched depends on a) current URL and b) URL params. I'm using React Router v4. So what I've done is basically put a lot of `switch` cases in that component. Which works and does what I want it to do, but I'd rather not have the switch cases in this HoC.

```
const fetchesData = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class FetchesData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
      this.state = {isLoading: true};
    }

    fetchData() {
      this.setState({isLoading: true});

      const {match, dispatch} = this.props;
      const {params} = match;

      let action = () => {};
      switch (match.path) {
      case '/': {
        action = () => dispatch(
          fetchPopularArticles()
        );
        break;
      }
      case '/artists/:slug': {
        action = () => dispatch(
          fetchArtistWithArticles(params.slug)
        );
        break;
      }
      // ... more
      }

      action()
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            isLoading: false,
          });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        !!this.state.isLoading ?
          <LoadingComponent/> :
          <WrappedComponent
            {...this.props}
          />
      );
    }
  }
  return withRouter(connect()(FetchesData));
};
```

I'd prefer to somehow inject the `fetchData()` function from the underlying component. Or maybe from parent (router) component.

The first I'm not sure if possible since it would have to mount the underlying component first, which brings more trouble than anything else.

And the former I'm not sure how I would go about doing either since I would need to know the params of the route.

My route rendering looks something like this:

```
[
  <Route
    exact={true}
    key={0}
    path={'/'}
    render={(props) => (
      <fetchesData(Home)
        {...props}/>
    )}/>,
  // ... more routes
]
```

What's a good practice for this?

If it helps here's the source:

- [HoC](https://github.com/d1am0nd/hiphop101/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/hoc/fetchesData/index.js)
- [Route rendering](https://github.com/d1am0nd/hiphop101/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/containers/Content/index.js)
- [Route definitions](https://github.com/d1am0nd/hiphop101/blob/master/resources/assets/js/routes/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in react data flows down the preferred way would be to pass `fetchData` method from `Render` component. You could pass the method to `fetchesData` like this

```
const FetchedHome = fetchesData(Home, fetchPopularArticles)
const FetchedArtists = fetchesData(Home, fetchArtistWithArticles) 
//   ....
<Route
exact={true}
key={0}
path={'/'}
render={(props) => (
  < FetchedHome {...props}/>
)}/>
```

And then inside `fetchesData` call the passed method

```
const fetchesData = (WrappedComponent, fetchMethod){
  //....
  componentDidMount() {
    const {match, dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(fetchMethod(match.params));
  } 
}
```

Change the action to accept an object

```
const fetchArtistWithArticles = ({slug: artistSlug})
```

If you don't want to change your actions you could pass a mapping object from match.params to function attributes you want to send.

Comment: How would I get the router params for calls like `fetchArtistWithArticles(params.slug)` in this case? Where `slug` is a router param. I don't need the `fetchData` method in the underlying component. I've also updated my question with the actual source if it helps in any way.

Comment: Note that react officially advices against using HoC in a render method because it would "remount" the whole component as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method

Comment: Thank you. I've added dots to emphasize declaration and call shouldn't be in same place.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating map functions. My HoC is much nicer now and fetch functions are in route definitions, which I find better than my old way.